# Client ID and Secret Secret for Translate API

Tags: azure, client, translate

I tried to test the translate api.  `Adm.py` on Microsoft git-hub (https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/Python-Speech-Translate) requires a `client_id` and a `client_secret`.  I only have a subscription ID and 2 keys.  I have tried every combination but nothing works. Where do I get a `client_id` and `client_secret`?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the link to the [Microsoft Cognitive Services API](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services), you need to register there and obtain an API key.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up Service Principal for API to API authentication. You can visit [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication) link to configure the same. Keys in the article is the client secret that you require. More information about this can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-application-objects)